# How to add UITextField,UITextView,UILabel and UIButton in UITableview like forms iphone?

Tags: forms, uitableview, uitextfield, uitextview, uilabel

In my iphone application there is 4 forms. These forms are having UITextField, UITextView, UILabel and UIButton. Currently i placed these items in UIScrollView. But, now my client want the forms look like 'iPhone Settings app'. How can i place the UITextView,UITextField, UILabel and UIButton in UITableView? The user need to enter their details in this forms, the tableview should move up when the user click the UITextField in bottom. How can do this? Please suggest me any sample code/ ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`UITableViewCell`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a view called [`contentView`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewCell_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITableViewCell/contentView).
Use `[cell.contentView addSubview:yourView]` to add the items to your cell.